# ENOENT: no such file or directory, when attempting to upload a file with playwright

Tags: typescript, playwright

I cant seem to figure out why the file Im trying to use as an upload wont work, I've created this upload function

```
async uploadFile(file: string) {
    await this.fileUploadIcon.click();
    expect(this.page.locator('.file-upload-input')).toBeVisible();
    await this.page.setInputFiles('.file-upload-input', file);
}
```

which is being used in the test:

```
test.only('Upload a document', async () => {
    await uploadActions.uploadFile(firstDoc);
});
```

the first doc is being initialized with this path:

```
const firstDoc = '../Assets/Automated_Doc_2.pdf';
```

but the test fails and the path besides the `ENOENT: no such file or directory` error looks correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share the folder structure and how you're running the tests?

Comment: The files I need to upload are in a folder I've labeled as `Assets` and that folder lives in this directory:
`C:\Users\myName\Desktop\Automation\TestAutomation\playwright` 

the playwright folder is where the rest of the project lives as well

Im running the tests by typing `npx playwright test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to await the expect -> `await expect...`.

Also I'd recommend to use `path.join(__dirname, '../Assets/Autoamted_Doc_2.pdf)` which is a better way of dealing with paths, since otherwise its CWD (current working directory) based.

To import path, you have to: `import path from 'path';`

Using both should make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a single slash I would use double slash in your path.

```
 C:\\Users\\myName\\Desktop\\Automation\\TestAutomation\\playwright.
```